# Why does assigning the body of an email (a String) to String object error?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying, in the trivial case, to extract Outlook email bodies and paste them into a Worksheet.

However, assigning the `.Body` (a String) property of `olMail` object to the `EmailBody` variable (also a String) triggers an *"Application-defined or object-defined error"*, at line `EmailBody = .Body` running the below code. I am using the same method seen on numerous other threads except looping through a restricted set of folder items. The `olMail.Class` = 43 (mailitem). Unsure why `ActiveExplorer`, `GetInspector` or the `NewMailEx` methods are necessary given the below code seems logical.

Why isn't this working?

### CODE

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
        ' Part 1
        
            Dim wb              As Workbook, _
                ws              As Worksheet, _
                tStamp1         As String, _
                EmailBody       As String, _
                wsCount         As Integer, _
                j               As Integer
                
                j = 2
                Set wb = ThisWorkbook
                Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                tStamp1 = Format(DateAdd("h", 10, Date - 3), "ddddd h:nn AMPM")
                
            Dim ol              As Outlook.Application, _
                ns              As Namespace, _
                fol             As MAPIFolder, _
                subFolderItems  As Outlook.Items, _
                olMail          As Object, _
                olMailID        As String, _
                StoreID         As String

                Set ol = New Outlook.Application
                Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
                Set fol = ns.Folders("[insert folder]").Folders("[insert folder]").Folders("[insert folder]")
                Set subFolderItems = fol.Items
                Set subFolderItems = subFolderItems.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" & tStamp1 & "' ")
                       
        ' Part 2
            
            Do
                wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
                If wsCount > 1 Then
                    wb.Worksheets(2).Delete
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Loop Until wsCount = 1
            
            For Each olMail In subFolderItems
                With olMail
                    If .Subject Like "*[insert subject]*" Then
                        
                        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
                        EmailBody = .Body
                        
                        With wb
                            .Worksheets.Add After:=.Worksheets(1)
                            .Worksheets(2).Range("A1").Value = EmailBody
                        End With
                        ElseIf .Subject = "[insert subject]" Then
                            .Display
                    
                    End If
                End With
            Next olMail

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

---

### EDIT #1

Substituted

```
                        olMailID = .EntryID
                        StoreID = fol.StoreID
                        Set olMail = ns.GetItemFromID(olMailID)
```

For

```
                        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
```

and the error now reverts to *"Application-defined or object-defined error"*.

---

### EDIT #2

Noticed in Locals window that the body carries no value

[image]

---

### EDIT #3

So, tried MS suggestions found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getinspector) but received the *same error* at line `Set wdDoc = myInspector.WordEditor`; which lead to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376329/mailitem-getinspector-wordeditor-in-office-2016-generates-application-defined-or), implying an Outlook security feature is preventing the extraction. Not fully confident this is the cause but does anybody have a better idea?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
        ' Part 1
        
            Dim wb              As Workbook, _
                ws              As Worksheet, _
                tStamp1         As String, _
                EmailBody       As String, _
                wsCount         As Integer, _
                j               As Integer
                
                j = 2
                Set wb = ThisWorkbook
                Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                tStamp1 = Format(DateAdd("h", 10, Date - 3), "ddddd h:nn AMPM")
                
            Dim ol              As Outlook.Application, _
                ns              As Namespace, _
                fol             As MAPIFolder, _
                subFolderItems  As Outlook.Items, _
                olMail          As Object, _
                olMailID        As String, _
                StoreID         As String

                Set ol = New Outlook.Application
                Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
                Set fol = ns.Folders("[insert folder]").Folders("[insert folder]").Folders("[insert folder]")
                Set subFolderItems = fol.Items
                Set subFolderItems = subFolderItems.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" & tStamp1 & "' ")
                              
            Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector, _
                wdDoc As Word.Document, _
                wdRange As Word.Range
                       
        ' Part 2
            
            Do
                wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
                If wsCount > 1 Then
                    wb.Worksheets(2).Delete
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Loop Until wsCount = 1
            
            For Each olMail In subFolderItems
                With olMail
                    If .Subject Like "*[insert subject]*" Then

                        .Display
                        Set myInspector = .GetInspector
                        Set wdDoc = myInspector.WordEditor
                        Set wdRange = wdDoc.Range(0, wdDoc.Characters.Count)
                        wdRange.InsertBefore ("EMAIL BODY")
                         
                    End If
                End With
            Next olMail

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

---

### EDIT #4

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234670/select-the-body-of-an-email-copy-it-and-paste-it-into-excel-using-vba) is the same approach as first described. I have copied it exactly and still find the same error at same place, so this must be security or Outlook upgrade related.

---

### EDIT #5

So, after rethinking through the problem, have tried navigating around the plausible security issue by running the below code in Outlook. Yet, the same error appears at line `.SaveAs (Str), olTXT` (enumeration and syntax seem fine).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
        
    Dim ol              As Application, _
        ns              As Namespace, _
        fol             As MAPIFolder, _
        subFolderItems  As Items, _
        olMail          As Object, _
        Str             As String, _
        tStamp1         As String

        tStamp1 = Format(DateAdd("h", 10, Date - 1), "ddddd h:nn AMPM")
        Set ol = New Application
        Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set fol = ns.Folders("[insert folder]").Folders("[insert folder]").Folders("[insert folder]")
        Set subFolderItems = fol.Items
        Set subFolderItems = subFolderItems.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" & tStamp1 & "' ")
    
    For Each olMail In subFolderItems
        With olMail
            If .Subject Like "*[insert subject]*" Then
                
                Str = "[insert file path]"
                Str = Str & .Subject & ".txt"

                .SaveAs (Str), olTXT
            
            End If
        End With
    Next olMail

End Sub
```

---

### EDIT #6

Looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204574/run-time-error-287-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-while-using) which lead to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/security/information-about-email-security-settings) where this section

[image]

is important. No Admin rights so avenue of enquiry is moot.

Comment: Why do this `Set olMail = ns.GetItemFromID(olMailID)` when you already have a reference to olMail ?  Likely that’s not a good idea inside a `with` block

Comment: `VBA 1004 Error` is a runtime error in VBA which is also known as `application-defined or object-defined` error and why is that because `we have limited number of columns` in excel and when our code gives the command to go out of range we get `1004 error`, there are other situations when we get this error when we refer to `a range which does not exist in the sheet`.
I think the email body is larger than what excel can handle. [Source](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-1004-error/)

Comment: @TimWilliams, due to trouble-shooting errors, the thinking was perhaps `olMail` hadn't instantiazed properly ... though local windows looked fine. How would blocking with `With` effect?

Comment: @TimWilliams, to clarify: removing `olMailID`, `StoreID` and setting 'olMail', results in the "Method 'Body' of object_'_MailItem' failed" error again.

Comment: @iѕєρєня, it is odd. Body contents are minimal, much too small to bother Excel size constraints. Had a look at the source link provided and didn't see any other associations to the current problem.

Comment: @GeoffreyTurner the link just talked about the error you've got. if the code gets at least one e-mail before it throws an error, you can check which mail is a problematic one. but if its not even starting, the error is wrong and you have to debug the code line by line. I don't use outlook, but if I would I could've check it on my PC to see if I can find the error root.

Comment: Have you tried `.HTMLBody`?

Comment: @JeremyThompson, same error sadly.

Comment: Is that a signed/encrypted message by any chance?

Comment: Hi @DmitryStreblechenko. Doesn't look to be - how do I check?

Comment: Look at the message icon in the Outlook Explorer for that message.

Comment: Not that I can see. Also ran an advanced search just in case.